# From where to download facebook connector for WSO2-ESB?

Tags: facebook, wso2, linkedin-api, esb, wso2-esb

I am trying to use social networking sites with WSO2 ESB. I have been able to successfully use twitter connector available on : 
            https://github.com/wso2/esb-connectors/tree/master/distribution/twitter
I am trying to search for facebook and linkedIN connectors for WSO2 - ESB, but cant find their .zip file.
Where can I download LinkedIN and Facebook connectors for WSO2-ESB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are not released yet. They are under development and will be released as soon. Meanwhile you can build and check the linkedIn from here, https://github.com/wso2/esb-connectors/tree/master/linkedin

Answer (score 0):

WSO2 has provided a public preview of their store at https://storepreview.wso2.com/store/, where you can find all the currently available connectors, including the Facebook connector at https://storepreview.wso2.com/store/assets/esbconnector/b615c2a4-a4a6-48f0-bbb2-c516af0cdd37